# 90s or early 2000s teen fantasy, parallel dimensions

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I read a couple books from this series over ten years ago and it has nagged at me ever since. The books were rather short and had scenes from the story on the cover. I don’t think it was a widely popular series either. I honestly don’t remember too many details other than:

- The characters are a group of teens (maybe four or five, with a mix of male and female) from the human world
- They accidentally get transported to a fantasy realm but they don’t know how it happens; they talk about events leading up to their arrival to figure things out
- The characters almost seemed like they had amnesia and had to figure out who they were
- They retain their normal/human identities
- They get transported back and forth between the worlds (I believe)

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: They regain their human identity - so had they been turned into monsters or something?

Comment: @jenayah: Could be they retained their essential appearance (no one changed gender, race, or species) or just indicating that, even if they didn't remember *who* they were, their personality was unchanged.

Comment: They retained their appearance and essential personalities other than forgetting what happened.

Comment: There is a series called Everworld by K.A.Applegate which has similar content.  There are 5 main characters, 3 male, 2 female.  They are transported to a fantasy world and are trying to work out how to survive and get back home.  It's a teen series, so the books are pretty short.  More detail can be found here: <https://www.bookseriesinorder.com/everworld/>

Comment: Thank you so much, Teryl!! It is “Everworld”!

Answer (score 2):

There is a series called Everworld by K.A.Applegate which has similar content. There are 5 main characters, 3 male, 2 female. They are transported to a fantasy world and are trying to work out how to survive and get back home. It's a teen series, so the books are pretty short. More detail can be found here: [bookseriesinorder.com/everworld](https://www.bookseriesinorder.com/everworld/)

Since it appears this was the right answer, I've shifted the comment to the answers section.  Glad I could be of assistance.

Comment: This is the Same. K.A. Applegate who initially penned the **Animorphs** books, correct?

Comment: Yes, @Russ Rainford, it certainly is the same K.A.Applegate (Katherine Applegate and her husband Michael Grant, writing together under the name K. A. Applegate) who penned Animorphs and other books including the SF series called Remnants.